# button click to give randomized image background (CSS + JavaScript + JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my code. Im new to JavaScript so idk what I'm really doing. Basically, every time the button is clicked, a new Van Gogh detail/image should fill the background. I feel like many images are repeated and sometimes the button doesn't work (a new image doesn't appear on each click). Ideally, I would like a new image with each click. For now, I only have 10 images, but may add more. Thank you for your help.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>VG java project</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/main.css">
    <script src="assets/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/main.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="container1"></div>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="button">
            Do you like Van Gogh? 
         </div>
         
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 3rem;
  z-index: 200;
  background: url(gogh4.jpg);
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;

}

.item {
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
  border: 7px double;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(225, 186, 253);
  opacity: 80%; 
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(197, 103, 247);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 90%; 
}

.gogh1 {
  background: url(gogh1.jpg);
}

.gogh2 {
  background: url(gogh3.jpg);
}

.gogh3 {
  background: url(gogh3.jpg);
}

.gogh4 {
  background: url(gogh4.jpg);
}

.gogh5 {
  background: url(gogh5.jpg);
}

.gogh6 {
  background: url(gogh6.jpg);
}

.gogh7 {
  background: url(gogh7.jpg);
}

.gogh8 {
  background: url(gogh8.jpg);
}

.gogh9 {
   background: url(gogh9.jpg);
}

.gogh10 {
   background: url(gogh10.jpg);
}

.highlight {
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

JavaScript ~ I'm using jQuery btw

```
$(function() {

  $(".button").click(function(){

    let goghs = ["gogh1", "gogh2", "gogh3", "gogh4", 
                "gogh5", "gogh6", "gogh7",  "gogh8",
                "gogh9", "gogh10"]
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random()* goghs.length - Math.random() + 2 );
    $("body").toggleClass(goghs[i]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since You asked for Javascript help.

Here's a problem you had in your code:

Edited:

```
$(function () {

  $(".button").click(function () {

    let goghs = ["gogh1", "gogh2", "gogh3", "gogh4",
      "gogh5", "gogh6", "gogh7", "gogh8",
      "gogh9", "gogh10"
    ]
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * goghs.length); //There was no need to add + Random plus 2 to it. You already Selecting a random index from an array(sometimes 'i' value was 10 -> undefined).
    console.log(i, goghs[i]); //logging helps you notice that is nothing wrong with other parts and function runs. only the code itself has some problems.
    $("body").toggleClass(goghs[i]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If "i" is 2 the first time around then "gogh2" get added as the class.

If "i" is 3 the second time around the "gogh3" will be 'added' to the class list.  "gogh2" will still be there.

Then, if "i" is 2 the third time around, then it will remove "gogh2" and you'll just be left with "gogh3".

Try:

```
$("body").removeClass();
$("body").addClass(goghs[i]);
```

and do away with your toggleClass line.

toggleClass will add the class to the list if it's not there and remove it if it is.